# Power BI - How to duplicate the group into multiple columns?

Tags: group-by, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm new to power BI and I'm facing an issue. I've searched the solution online but haven't found it.

I have collected the response from a questionnaire. Here is the data example:

[Response of my questionnaire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHwDI.png)

Now I want to make a chart to show the result with 3 types of response, which are "Positive", "Neutral" and "Negative". So, I have grouped "Agree" and "Totally Agree" into "Positive", "Neither Agree Nor Disagree" into "Neutral" and "Disagree" and "Totally Disagree" into "Negative". But I can just make the group effective for first column only.

So it there any method for me to apply the group setting into every column? It seems so time-consuming to make the new group for every column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to tell exactly the output you want to get, but potentially this

Add column ... index column ...

Right click index column and unpivot other columns

Merge the Value column against another table you [Text / Alternate Text] have and expand the alternate description. Here I am using Table1 as that other table

If you want, then click on attribute column and transform...pivot column, with the new column as values to get back into same format

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Value"}, Table1, {"Column1"}, "Bucket", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Bucket", {"Column2"}, {"Column2"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Table1",{"Value"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Column2"),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in  #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

Alternatively, since there are only 5 possibilities, do an edit-replace across all the columns

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"Agree","Positive",Replacer.ReplaceText,Table.ColumnNames(Source)),
#"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","Totally Agree","Positive",Replacer.ReplaceText,Table.ColumnNames(Source)),
#"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value1","Neither Agree Nor Disagree","Neutral",Replacer.ReplaceText,Table.ColumnNames(Source))
in #"Replaced Value2"
```

**EDIT**
You can directly include Table1 translation table in your query, if you don't want to create a separate query for it:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
Table1 = #table({"Column 1", "Column 2"},{{"Agree","Positive"},{"Totally Agree","Positive"},{"Neither Agree Nor Disagree","Neutral"},{"Disagree","Negative"},{"Totally Disagree","Negative"}}), 
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Value"}, Table1, {"Column1"}, "Bucket", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Bucket", {"Column2"}, {"Column2"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Table1",{"Value"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Column2"),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in  #"Removed Columns1"
```

Comment: Wow, I have tried the second way and it works. Thanks a lot. But I'm kinda lost on the first one. How can I merge the Value column against the table 1? Do I have to put the table 1 into the same data sheet?

Comment: You need a query that has the translation table in it that you can merge against the other query.  That can be a separate query read from data on any tab on the file, or embedded in the query itself. See edit above

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation.
In my case, I went to Power Query and duplicated the table then transformed all question columns into lines to have only one column. You can also try this and add a custom column with your criteria.

Table 1.
[image: Image of contet table in portuguese]

Duplicate Table
[image: Duplicate table]

Code:

```
let
    Source = #"Pesquisa Desligamento",
    #"Outras Colunas Removidas" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"ID", "Esta satisfeito com o Pacote de remuneracao", "A oportunidade atendeu a Expectativa", "Esta satisfeito com o Relacionamento com os lideres ****", "Esta satisfeito com Relacionamento ****", "Gostou de trabalhar na ****"}),
    #"Colunas Não Dinâmicas" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Outras Colunas Removidas", {"ID"}, "Atributo", "Valor"),
    #"Colunas Renomeadas" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Colunas Não Dinâmicas",{{"Atributo", "Pergunta"}, {"Valor", "Resposta"}})
in
    #"Colunas Renomeadas"
```

In Dax I created measures for each question in case I had to see one question in particular, but for a overall temperature of yours questionnarie, this might work